# Correlate HTML element name with Django form field name

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I correlate HTML element (input) name and "Django" form field name?

For example, I have HTML file:

```
...
<input name='some_name'>
...
```

And I have the Django form with "name" field:

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField()
```

When I create a form, pass data to it and invoke "is_valid":

```
form = SomeForm(request.data)
form.is_valid()
```

I have an error for "name" field: "This field is required". So, what I can I do if changing input name in HTML is undesirable?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're rendering `SomeForm` in your html at all. Have you passed `SomeForm` to the template and rendered it?

Comment: In this case "yes", I do not render a template. Since this in not my code and there are a lot of JavaScript there I decided that it will be better to do not touch HTML and make changes in Django views.

Comment: Then you don't need to define `SomeForm`, as you're not using it, and that's why it can't be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're not rendering your form in template, then you don't even need to define it. 
It's not valid in your case simply because it has no data bound to it.
You can always access your POST data in a view like this - `request.POST['name']` 
Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

Answer (score 0):

They are named like your model attributes so it would be 'name' in your case.
And check if passing `request.data` as the 'data' argument for `SomeForm` is the proper way for you. I'd rather use `request.POST`.

Another way to do it:
You can pass your `SomeForm` instance to view context and render a ready to go form in your template:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    # code
    context['form'] = SomeForm() # with data or not
    return context
```

and then in your template:

```
{{ form }}
```

or iterate through it:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

that's always a way to do it and discover how django is naming your input's.